# GTK+ 3 or PyGObject for Quickly

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygobject

First answer on [this question](https://answers.launchpad.net/quickly/+question/194811) says that Quickly supports GObject introspection and GTK+ 3. Is this means that it USES GObject or it USES GTK+ 3? I ask this because I want to start learning GUI programming with Quickly and Python, so I'm not sure I need to learn GObject or GTK+ 3, so please help me and answer me on this question too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both GTK+ 2 and 3 are based on GObject. You are probably confusing PyGTK and
GObject introspection. PyGTK was never able to access GTK+ 3, is deprecated and
not maintained any more. So, you should learn to use GTK+ 3 through GObject
introspection. See for example [these resources](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Big, big thanks. @matthias You really explained what I've asked. Just to confirm, when I learn GTK+ 3 I learn GObject at the same time? Also, I see that quickly is some kind of tool that makes gui programming with glade, python and gtk+ 3 easier (am I right?). But also I see that when I look at the gtk+ 3 (and python) tutorials they don't include glade (niether quickly). So, my question is, will I be able to make gui programs with quickly when I learn GTK+ 3 without problems? I mean, I'll be able to implement all these stuff from GTK+ 3 when using quickly (and glade of course)? Thanks.

Comment: You will probably not come in direct contact with GObject, it's just the base class for all the GUI widgets. Indeed, most tutorials start with manual construction of GUIs but that's just to show how to interact with them. Even if you design your GUI with Glade you will have to connect the signals to some behaviour. By the way, that tutorial has some info about Glade [at the end](http://.python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html)